# How to use teamcity to run parallel cypress tests

Tags: teamcity, cypress

I am using teamcity-ci to run cypress tests. For now, cypress doesn't support parallel tests in teamcity. Maybe cypress parallel test support is related with the dashboard.

If I don't use the cypress dashboard. Is it possible to run cypress test in parallel in teamcity.

I run my test in by `docker-compose run cypress`

Comment: This is very interesting, if I had to do it, maybe the cypress parallelization would be easiest to achieve via TC agent containers. There are some licence limitations and known networking issues, though.

Comment: I guess I need to try a supported ci server

Comment: To use cypress' built in parallel functionality you need to use the dashboard.  You could write a script to iterate over your spec files and distribute them to individual jobs in team city if you don't want to use the dashboard.

Comment: If just custom made script to divide the tests across jobs in team city is not good enouch. For instance one of your CI node is running more tests than the others and is your bottle neck then you may want to try something more advanced.

Comment: The tests can be allocated across CI nodes in a dynamic way to auto-balance the CI nodes timing to get the shortest CI build time. 

I'm working on CI parallelization since last few years and I developed into my product an integration for Cypress https://github.com/KnapsackPro/knapsack-pro-cypress

Example how it works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6ixK4IK-3Y

Do you look for something simple and free solution or maybe you already developed custom-made script you could share?

Comment: I can suggest an open-source alternative that coordinates parallelization.  https://github.com/agoldis/sorry-cypress

Answer (score 1):

For other options apart from agoldis. Pls have a look at here,

[Parallel Cypress tests on TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57168488/parallel-cypress-tests-on-teamcity/59496958#59496958)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on an open-source, self-hosted "dashboard". You can run it with your test suite - it will parallelize the tests:

1. Start a container from this image https://hub.docker.com/r/agoldis/sorry-cypress-director
2. [Reconfigure cypress](https://github.com/agoldis/sorry-cypress/blob/master/README.md#reconfiguring-cypress) test runner to use the URL of the service from step 1
3. Run cypress as usual: `cypress run --parallel --record --key <anystring> --ci-build-id <uniqueBuildId>`

Comment: I am using the directory service. It's really painless to spin it up and parallelize.